# Need to highlight distribution area using google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In google maps, when you search a city/province/country it highlights it red. I would like to the same to display a distribution area e.g. highlight all the cities/provinces/countries where a specified item is sold.

Anyone got any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. You will need to use KML layers to do this.